# Select unexist date yyyy/mm

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a SQL query as follows:

```
SELECT 
    R.BOOK_YM, COUNT(*) 
FROM  
    #TB_TRANSED_GUI_AMOUNT AS R
GROUP 
    BY R.BOOK_YM
```

The selected results like as follows:

```
BOOK_YM  | count(*)  
---------+---------
201411   | 51 
201412   | 142 
201501   | 1 
201506   | 1
```

How do I modify the result like the follows:

```
BOOK_YM | count(*)    
--------+-----------
201411  | 51 
201412  | 142 
201501  | 1 
201502  | 0 
201503  | 0 
201504  | 0 
201505  | 0 
201506  | 1
```

Comment: In this table `#TB_TRANSED_GUI_AMOUNT` exists your expected values?

Comment: Does those values with count = 0 exist somewhere in your tables? If not, consider a help table with all possible BOOK_YM values.

Comment: @jarlh I guess they don't exist, based on the title as well as on the select statement he presented...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following to get a table of all YYYYMM between 2 dates and use the resulting @YMList variable in a join:

```
declare @StartDate date = cast(dateadd(month, -12, GetDate()) as date)
declare @EndDate date = cast(GetDate() as date)
declare @YMList TABLE (YYYYMM INT)

;with dates as (
    SELECT cast(@StartDate as Date) [date]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(month,1,t.date)
    FROM dates t
    WHERE t.[date] < @EndDate
)
insert @YMList (YYYYMM)
select 
    YEAR([Date]) * 100 + MONTH([Date]) AS YYYYMM
from dates
WHERE [Date] < @EndDate
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 10000)
```

Comment: Hi,Metaphor:   It really works..Thanks for you help. However, the type of parameters ,@StartDate and @EndDate, must be char(6) instead of date.  How can I fix it?

Comment: Convert the char(6) to a date with this - cast(@charyyyymm + '01' as date)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (I think `BOOK_YM` is a `varchar` field if not `CAST` it)

```
SELECT
    Y.YYYY + M.MM AS BOOK_YM, 
    COUNT(R.BOOK_YM) AS CNT
FROM
    (SELECT SUBSTRING(BOOK_YM, 1, 4) As YYYY
     FROM t
     GROUP BY SUBSTRING(BOOK_YM, 1, 4)) AS Y
    CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT '01' As MM
     UNION ALL SELECT '02'
     UNION ALL SELECT '03'
     UNION ALL SELECT '04'
     UNION ALL SELECT '05'
     UNION ALL SELECT '06'
     UNION ALL SELECT '07'
     UNION ALL SELECT '08'
     UNION ALL SELECT '09'
     UNION ALL SELECT '10'
     UNION ALL SELECT '11'
     UNION ALL SELECT '12') AS M
    LEFT JOIN
    t AS R
    ON Y.YYYY + M.MM = R.BOOK_YM
WHERE 
    Y.YYYY + M.MM BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(BOOK_YM) FROM t) AND (SELECT MAX(BOOK_YM) FROM t)
GROUP BY 
    Y.YYYY + M.MM
```